# How to remove the header of the first page of the bibligraphy?

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{keeppage}{\let\thispagestyle=\@gobble}{}
\makeatother
```

And wrap the table of contents like so:

```
\begin{keeppage}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{keeppage}
```

[image]

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}` would do the job. If you don't want page numbers too then use `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Thanks Harish, i have tried it like this: \thispagestyle{plain} \begin{keeppage} \bibliography{biblio} \end{keeppage}, it does not work!

Comment: You don't need `keeppage`. Just use `\thispagestyle{plain} \bibliography{biblio} `

Comment: now the probvlem is on the page number of the first page of the bibliography, it is removed?!

Comment: We need to know some very basic things about your document, such as the document class that's in use. Please edit your posting to provide these pieces of information.

Comment: I use , \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}.

Comment: We need to see more to help you, to be precise, we need a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- Link).